# Dynamic Menu item no show Icon

Tags: android

I mount my NavigationView dynamically like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //nvDrawer is mount
        Menu menu = nvDrawer.getMenu();
        for (MyMenuItem kmi : menus.values()) {
            menu.add(kmi.getText());
            MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(menu.size() - 1);

            mi.setTitle(kmi.getText());
            Drawable dIcon =
                    getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                            .getIdentifier(S
                            tring.valueOf(kmi.getIconId()), "drawable", getPackageName()));
            mi.setIcon(dIcon);
        }
  }
```

So, I debug and the dIcon is setted, but the icon there appears in running app.
Every menus appears, but none icon appears, just silver rectangles.

P.S: My icons are png images.

I'm waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimmy,
If you're running your code on Android 3.0+, the icons in the menu are not shown by design. This is a design decision by Google.

You can read more about it below on Android developers blog.
Hope it helps.
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: I'm adding menus in a NavigationView, using https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer as base to my code.

Comment: I try this:  mi.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
Not work. :(